# How to get following output from this input =>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an Array of Objects like:

```
var temp= 
[{Level: "District", Product: "Duplacor", MustBe: "Less Than", Value: 50000},
{Level: "District", Product: "Amcor", MustBe: "Less Than", Value: 100000},
{Level: "District", Product: "Juxtiva", MustBe: "Greater than", Value: 500000},
{Level: "District", Product: "Juxtiva", MustBe: "Less than", Value: 1500000},
{Level: "District", Product: "Amcor", MustBe: "Greater than", Value: 50000}];
```

I need an output like

**Product MinValue MaxValue**

Ex: **Juxtiva 500000 1500000**

Please note: Product Names are not static, they may change in back-end , so we cannot hard-code the product names, we have to use the array to retrieve the Product Names ( **Not all** product names will have both less than , greater than values , will have one of them atleast)

Comment: Awesome, now give us some code that implies you even tried the problem and we can then help!

Comment: What will be the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` for product `Duplacor`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kpxdcrsf/  @WilomGfx

Comment: I tried my best and I have the answer as well. But I am in search of the most optimized and best way to do the same @WilomGfx

Comment: @darshanmantri good but next time post it right away, this is not a coding as a service platform, most people wont help unless you prove you at least tried something.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point to group your data by product with a min/max. It should be trivial to output it:

```js
function process(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((map, o) => {
        const product = o.Product;
        if (!map[product]) {
            map[product] = { min: null, max: null};
        }
        const prop = o.MustBe === 'Greater than' ? 'min' : 'max';
        map[product][prop] = o.Value;
        return map;
    }, {});
}

console.log(process([{
    Level: "District",
    Product: "Duplacor",
    MustBe: "Less Than",
    Value: 50000
}, {
    Level: "District",
    Product: "Amcor",
    MustBe: "Less Than",
    Value: 100000
}, {
    Level: "District",
    Product: "Juxtiva",
    MustBe: "Greater than",
    Value: 500000
}, {
    Level: "District",
    Product: "Juxtiva",
    MustBe: "Less than",
    Value: 1500000
}, {
    Level: "District",
    Product: "Amcor",
    MustBe: "Greater than",
    Value: 50000
}]));
```

Comment: Thanks @Evan Trimboli.

Comment: I did it in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/kpxdcrsf/ . But your answer is really helpful and seems to be structured way of doing the same. Appreciated